# Googlemap sometimes crashes app when use com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.MoveCamera

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, kotlin, google-play-services

I'm having some trouble with google maps library. It's a weird issue, I had seen reported since 2013 but it is still there...

Some times when I load a map to show the current position, the app crashes. The map is inside of a fragment:

```
class MyFragment: Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{
```

The error is in this function:

```
private fun actualizarPosicionMapa(coordenadas: MisCoordenadas){
    try{
        val latLng = LatLng(coordenadas.coordenadasLatitud?.toDouble() ?: 0.0, coordenadas.coordenadasLongitud?.toDouble() ?: 0.0)
        val cameraPosition = CameraPosition.Builder().target(latLng).zoom(Constantes.General.zoomMap).build()
        val cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition)
        if(cameraUpdate != null && mMap != null){
            //the error is triggered at the next line
            mMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate)//this one line!
        }
    }
    catch (ex: Exception){
        Log.wtf("errorMapBOOM", ex.message)
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), ex.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Crashlitics error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException Attempt to get length
 of null array java.nio.ByteBufferAsShortBuffer.put
 (ByteBufferAsShortBuffer.java:121)
 com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.buffer.d.d (d.java:71)
 com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.buffer.d.a (d.java:52)
 com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.a.a (a.java:56)
 com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bq.b (bq.java:47)
 com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bq.a (bq.java:41)
 com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.cd.a (cd.java:365)
 com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bf.run (bf.java:112)
```

The min api level I selected for the app was 19.

Lastest map version:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
```

Manifest:

```
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="MY_MAPS_API_KEY_:)" />
```

Comment: Can you please post your full maps-related code so that we can reproduce this error from our side?

Comment: I am seeing exactly the same error in the field sometimes, but not able to reproduce the error myself.